# Aspx page does not open the first time in new browser session

Tags: asp.net

I have an application running in IIS7 with Windows Server 2008R2. When I open a new browser page and call any ASPX page directly (eg. www.mysite.com/registration.aspx) I get redirected to the home page (index.html).

When I refresh the aspx page it renders properly. Also if I call any other aspx page after this first failed attempt they all open properly.

I don't get any error, the aspx page just gets redirected.

I've been struggling on this. Appreciate help.

Comment: Do you only have this issue at the Windows Server 2008 R2? So it is working locally?

Comment: Page works fine on localhost